# How evict spring cache by cacheNames?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cache

In my app, I have tow cache like this :

```
@Cacheable(cacheNames = "user", key= "#userId")
public User queryUserDetail(Long userId) {
    ......
}
@Cacheable(cacheNames = "address", key= "#addressId")
public Address queryAddressDetail(Long addressId) {
    ......
}
```

I want clear all cache if the cacheNames is "user":

```
@CacheEvict(cacheNames = "user", allEntries = true)
public void clearAllUserCache() {}
```

but it also cleared the cache with cacheNames "address",

How can I just clear the cache with the cacheNames "user"

Comment: Code looks fine. It should be evicting only the user. Are you using a simple cache or some cache library like ehCache etc?

Comment: I use spring data redis

Comment: Just to debug more, can you change the cache type to simple and try? `spring.cache.type : simple` . This will not use redis and instead use java `ConcurrentHashMap`.

Comment: when i user    spring.cache.type : simple, it correctly cleared the cache...very strange

Comment: So there you go.. Check your redis implementation on key management once again? From the code you posted, it looks fine.